# assocition methods on active record relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I retrieve a contact like this...

```
c = Contact.where(:user_id => 37)
```

I can't take advantage of the association the contact has with the Province.rb model, as `c.province` would produce a no method error.

```
 Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = 37
=> [#<Contact id: 13, firm: "aldjflkads", address: "55 SO Avenue", city: "Toronto", postalcode: "M3A B2B", mobile: "999 999 999", office: "", user_id: 37, created_at: "2013-05-02 18:52:01", updated_at: "2013-05-02 18:52:01", province_id: 6>]
>> c.province
NoMethodError: undefined method `province' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fbe94bd9cf0>
```

However, when I find a contact by user id this way....

```
>> c = Contact.find_by_user_id(37)
```

I can then call `c.province` and `c.province.name`

```
 Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = 37 LIMIT 1
=> #<Contact id: 13, firm: "aldjflkads", address: "55 aldjfla;skfj", city: "Toronto", postalcode: "M4G B2B", mobile: "999 999 999", office: "", user_id: 37, created_at: "2013-05-02 18:52:01", updated_at: "2013-05-02 18:52:01", province_id: 6>
>> c.province
  Province Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "provinces".* FROM "provinces" WHERE "provinces"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1
=> #<Province id: 6, name: "Ontario", created_at: "2013-04-19 02:37:11", updated_at: "2013-04-19 02:37:11">
>> c.province.name
=> "Ontario"
```

Question: Is there a way I can take advantage of association methods if I retrieve data like this

```
Contact.where(:user_id => 37)
```

**Update**

My Contact.rb model belongs_to :provinces, however, there's other data (address, postal code etc) that's native to the contact model. Therefore, if I did this (as suggested in the first answer), it would only allow me to access the province, not any of the other details I need.

```
@contactdetails = Contact.where({:user_id => @user.id}).first.province
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c = Contact.where(:user_id => 37).first.province

where() returns a collection.. whereas find_by_id assumes a unique result and only returns one

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, it creates a little bit of a problem  for me, given how my contact model works. I wonder if you might look at the update in my OP and make a suggestion.

Comment: Maybe I should just do Contact.find_by_user_id so I get a unique result